# PyCharm: Running Pylint from docker image

Tags: docker, pycharm, pylint

I've installed the PyLint PyCharm plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11084-pylint). I can get the linting to work if I choose the default project interpreter to be the one installed on my Windows laptop, but my project interpreter is the one on my attached Docker image. When the program default interpreter is the one on the Docker image, the PyLint plugin complains of:

> The project interpreter is missing Pylint, which is needed to properly check the imports.

I've installed pylint on the docker image, it does not however show up package list when looking in File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter

Does anyone know if the PyLint plugin should work with this workflow?

Answer (score 2):

To run Pylint in a Docker container I configured it as an external tool.

[Edit Tool window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb7DG.png)

Program:

```
docker-compose
```

Arguments:

```
run --rm django pylint --msg-template="$ProjectFileDir$/{path}:{line}:{column}: {msg_id}: {msg} ({symbol})" $FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$
```

[msg-template](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/output.html#pylint-output) argument makes each file path clickable so you can easily navigate to a line with a problem.